# RabbitMQ PHP: receive from a queue and send response to another

Tags: php, multithreading, rabbitmq, amqp, php-amqplib

I'm using RabbitMQ and PHP-AMQP to do some time consuming operations.

I have a Producer that send tasks to a queue -> One or multiplie workers listening to that queue and doing the time consuming operation  -> a receiver that increments a variable when a worker is done.

I used an exchange between workers and receivers. Problem is that my receiver also increments its variable when the producer emits logs...

**Here's a picture :**
[image: Diagram]

How can i simply separate this 2 queues so that my receiver only knows messages from the worker (Consumer) ?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you correctly, but  you can simply add another queue instead of exchanging? And then your worker-consumer will be a producer for it, and receiver will be a consumer.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for you response, i'll try it next. What I did in the meantime was just publishing from my consumer to a specific exchange like this.  http://imgur.com/SQmtY4i

Comment: I used this for my worker/consumer without declaring any exchange and it works fine.. Not sure if it's the simpliest method though : $that->channel->basic_publish($msglog, $task_name."exch");